# BeanFieldGroup in Vaadin with a List<String> as comma separated entry

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have the following POJO

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private List<String> emails;

 // getter & setter
}
```

in my form I use the `BeanFieldGroup` to bind the properties to the form.

But how can I done it easily, that the `emails` field can be entered as comma separated entries and this is then converted to a `List` of Strings ?

I assume I need a `Converter` for this, but i cannot find any method in the `FieldGroup` for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `FieldGroup` you need to use [FieldGroupFieldFactory](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/fieldgroup/FieldGroupFieldFactory.html). You can find example in [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-itembinding.html)

Comment: thanks for that - I actually solved this in creating my own TextField and adding a `Converter` to this and then bind it to the group. I will though look at the `FieldGroupFieldFactory`

Comment: As you have found out yourself you solve your problem with a converter. It is not needed to use a `FieldGroupFieldGroupFactory` here.